# how to get relative path from properties file

Tags: java, path, log4j, relative-path

I have a property file in my application where i have put the absolute path as key and value now i want to get this path in my log4j.xml file for file appender.
but i am not able to get path from there and how can i set this property file in my system's set properties.

```
#properties File

folderPrefix = D:\\MyProject

# path for logfiles

logfilePath = ${folderPrefix}/Framework/logs

<appender name="allLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${logfilePath}/log.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%-5p - %m%n [%c:%M] (%F:%L)%n" />
        </layout> 
    </appender>
```